# How to add an audio file to a shell script

Tags: shell-script, mplayer, sox, ogg, vorbis

How can I add an audio file (OGG vorbis) into a shell script making the script as small as possible and at the same time being able to execute it on as most systems as possible? I want the audio file be played.

I don’t want it to be `uuencode`d, because sharutils are not installed on many systems. base64 is nice, but makes the file/script bigger, which I don’t want.

Should I use `mplayer` or the `play` command from the sox package? Is it more common on Linux/BSD systems? Or is there another media player mostly installed? Should I convert the audio file to another format/codec (if that doesn’t make the file much bigger) to have more possible players to play the file back or is OGG vorbis a good choice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following script it works (using `mplayer`, which is probably not present on many systems).

```
#!/bin/sh
grep -A 1000 --text -m 1 ^Ogg "$0" | mplayer -
exit
OggS^@^B^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^]f<8a>g^@^@^@^@lYß¸^A^^^Avorbis^@^@^@^@^A"V^@^@^...
```

The last line is the beginning of the audio file binary.

The `grep` command searches for the first occurrence of *Ogg* in the file `$0` (which is the script file itself) and prints 1000 lines after that line (is enough for my small audio test file). The output of `grep` is then piped to `mplayer` which is reading `/dev/stdin` (abbreviation for `/dev/stdin` is `-`).

I have created this file by concatenating the script file `playmeBashScript.sh` with the audio file `sound.ogg`:

```
cat playmeBashScript.sh sound.ogg > playme.sh
```

---

A more general and a bit shorter version with `sed` instead of `grep` (thanks to Elias):

```
#!/bin/sh
sed 1,/^exit$/d "$0" | mplayer -
exit
OggS^@^B^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^]f<8a>g^@^@^@^@lYß¸^A^^^Avorbis^@^@^@^@^A"V^@^@^...
```

In this case `sed` selects all lines from number one up to the line where it finds the word *exit* and deletes them. The rest is pasted and piped to `mplayer`. Of course that only works if the word *exit* occurs only once in the script before the binary data.

Comment: It will probably be better to use `sed 1,/^Ogg/d "$0" | mplayer -` instead.

Comment: @elias no that does not work. The `Ogg` is part of the audio file (the first three bytes of it) and your command deletes this line (as far as I understand it). If I apply your command to my playme.sh file, the output is to small, does not play.

Comment: oh, alright, then maybe using another separator and then using: `sed 1,/^BEGIN_FILE/d "$0" | mplayer -`. I just thought it could be a more general solution. =)

Comment: Yes, ok. That is more general than having to tweak the number of output lines at grep’s `-A` option. I will change my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your script should contain also the concatenated data:

```
#!/bin/sh

TMPFILE=$(mktemp)
trap "rm ${TMPFILE}" 0 1 2 3 11 15
tail -n +7 $0 ${TMPFILE}
exec mplayer ${TMPFILE}
```

Let's call the script `omniplay`. So you need to cat your ogg-file 
appending to the script:

```
cat file.ogg >> omniplay
chmod +x omniplay
./omniplay
```

This is a standard method used by many install.sh files. Look also for `gzexe`.
You may also adjust the tail lines.

Comment: Has your version any advantages over my version? I don’t like it because it is longer. And I’d rather read the data directly from the file instead of writing it into a temporary file. Imagine the media file is 10 GB in size. Not a good idea to put that into a temporary file first.